# Excel 2007 Save as PDF with pagesize/pagewidth auto or not breaking Excel lines

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, export

I tried to export an Excel file into PDF, but it looks horrible. I need at least that one row form Excel to be saved into a one row in PDF.

I know that it is not so simple, because Excel does no have any page size. At least, they could make some estimations.

Can anyone recommend me how to save in MS Office an excel file into PDF, to have a normal look?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing to PDF or paper, look in the Page Layout section of the Excel 2007 ribbon. In the Page Setup section you can set:

- Margins (narrow preset is nice when it just doesn't quite fit)
- Paper Orientation
- Paper size
- Print Area (select the visible area you want to print, and choose Set Print Area. This will prevent printing a lot of extra white space

Some very useful options are not among the visible icons, you need to click the little square->arrow to access the Page Setup options. Among these tabs you will find:

- Fit to x by x pages. This will force the output to fit, zooming out a bit if necessary. It is crucial to set your Print Area properly to benefit from this option.
- Center on page
- Headers/Footers (tip: adding page numbering and printing an entire workbook at once will show the total pages of all worksheets)
- Rows to repeat at top / Columns to repeat at left. Similar to the Freeze Window Pane concept, this will repeat the select rows on top (or left) of every page if your table spans several pages. Usually used to include table headers and titles.

Whenever you start playing with the Paper size/orientation and Print Preview, you will see dotted lines that tells you what fits on the page or not. So you can adjust your things until it fits as you want it.

Answer (score 1):

when you're using a PDF printer (e.g. CutePDF) you can adjust the margins or change the layout to Landscape rather than Portrait. you'll get exactly what you see in the print preview.

Comment: And what is the WorkSheet is larger?